# Why I am seeing a spike of 9V on output and capacitor in 555 timer

Tags: timer, 555

I would like to have high voltage at output initially for a period of time, then low and high ... . But in the following circuit, I see spikes on output (green) and capacitor (blue) for a short period of time.

Can anyone explain?

[image: 555 time circuit]

Comment: The graph is clean. Where do you see spikes?

Comment: at the beginning of the graff. The capacitor is decreasing fro 9 V.

Comment: WhatRoughBeast and Gregory, I am just simulating with LTspice simulation circuit.

Comment: No way i would notice that. It's some kind of boundary condition of the simulator. Probably you could change it by defining the capacitor precharched.

Comment: I can't help you because I have no idea what `V(n003)` and `V(n004)` is.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is an artifact of the way the simulator operates. It starts by assuming that any capacitor is charged up to its' "natural" level. In this case, the combination of R1 and R2 cause the simulator to set the capacitor voltage to 9 volts, since that is the DC level you expect with the 555 not doing anything. And, when setting the start levels, the 555 inputs don't draw any particular current and the discharge transistor is not turned on. So the cap gets set to 9 volts.

Comment: Why would we see 9V on output (green) at 0 seconds in the graff?

Comment: If you want the simulation to be more realistic setup the 9V source supply in the advanced "pulse" mode. Set the initial voltage at 0V and an initial delay of say 1msec. Then set the rise time of 10msec to the on voltage of 9V. This technique will have the simulation start out like a real circuit does with no power and then turns on similar to when you would turn on a power switch.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that practically the output start with 9V and capacitor starts charging from 0V when I turn on the power supply?

Comment: @ShivaMudide - With no power applied, there is no current available to charge the capacitor. So, yes, with no power applied the capacitor voltage is zero.